# How to keep track of new plugins published on wordpress.org?

Tags: plugins

Is there any RSS feed to keep track of the [Newest Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/browse/new/) published on wordpress.org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Found it from the dashboard widget code, its http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss/browse/new/

As a workaround, you can use Page2rss.com to create a feed for that page - http://page2rss.com/page?url=wordpress.org/extend/plugins/browse/new/

Comment: Thank you Ashfame, I thought of that possibility, just as a last resort.

Let's see if someone comes up with a another solution, otherwise I'll mark yours as correct.

Comment: @janogarcia Found it :)

Comment: Amazing Ashfame. Just what I was looking for, great idea! Thanks a million.

Comment: Happy to help! :)